# c# can't load font in linux

Tags: c#, linux, fonts, bitmap

I'm trying to save an Image with text on it. It's a .NET Core program and on windows everything works fine.

```
private static Bitmap drawText(string s)
{
    PrivateFontCollection collection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    collection.AddFontFile(Path.GetFullPath("font.ttf"));
    FontFamily fontFamily = collection.Families[0];
    float fontSize = 32f;
    Font font = new Font(fontFamily, fontSize);
    int w = 750;

    Color neutral = Color.FromArgb(150, 150, 150);
    var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(s, font, w);

    bmp = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(size.Width), Convert.ToInt32(size.Height));
    g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50));

    var stringFormat = new StringFormat();
    stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    g.DrawString(s, font, new SolidBrush(neutral), new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), stringFormat);

    return bmp;
}
```

This code

```
var bmp = drawText("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
bmp.Save(Path.GetFullPath("text.png"));
```

creates the following image:
[image]

However, when I compile my program to run on linux-x64, no image gets created. The code stops at line `PrivateFontCollection collection = new PrivateFontCollection();`

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Core at you using?  Following says it works with Core 3.0/3,1 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: There seems to be issues with this, even in Core 3.1: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26460

Comment: What do you mean by "The code stops"? Does it throw an error? Does it just sit there doing nothing?

Comment: It's .Net Core version 3.1

Comment: I don't know, when I run the code on linux, it's not in debug mode and in addition to that, it's a discord bot so it doesn't throw an exception, instead it just continues with the rest of the code.